# Overriding a method with a ref struct param in older C# versions

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, c#-7.2

I'm trying to override a `JsonConverter<T>` in the `System.Text.Json` package which has an abstract Read method which can be ovveridden as:

> public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)

(Link to custom serialization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).)

Here `ref Utf8JsonReader` marks reader as a ref struct. "ref struct" is a feature introduced in 7.2. (which if you're not familiar is a struct that's meant to be used only on the stack. [MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#:%7E:text=ref%20struct.%20Beginning%20with%20C#%207.2,%20you%20can,the%20usage%20of%20ref%20struct%20types%20as%20follows:))

In my organization, one of our projects runs on an old compiler that can target only upto C# 6. Is there a way to write MSIL or code in C# 6 that can override the method signature and implement a derivative class of the above signature?

Otherwise you will see the following error:
*Struct 'System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader' is obsolete: Types with embedded references are not supported in this version*

Comment: hmm.. In this scenario, I would look to nuget packages that might add that support.  Alot of language features are prototyped and developed in previous versions before being shipped out afterall.

Comment: The `ref` here designates the argument to be _passed by reference_ instead of by value. It does not change the nature of the argument type. Also in your post please indicate which type is a structure and which is a class.

Comment: Can you please show what do you have now and what  is the problem? You can't override what is overriden already. Pls show original code.

Comment: Nothing special in my code, I merely had the above override which would work fine on c# 7.2+ compatible compilers. The abstract class incase you're interested is `JsonConverter` in `System.Text.Json` package.

I'm just trying to find a way to circumvent overriding it using older syntax of c#. Anyway for now I've just moved these converters to a seperate project which isn't touched by the old compiler pipeline.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou the Utf8JsonReader is the ref struct.

Comment: ref in parameters is not new, that has been there for ages, and that includes `ref StructType` in the parameter list, nothing new here. Are you being proactive thinking you *might* get a problem here, or have you already verified that the compiler doesn't compile that code?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen of course i've tested it in older versions. I can't make a derivative that is without the ref. This would work fine with ref to a class, however ref struct is a C# 7.2 feature.

Comment: I know you can't make an override without the ref **but do you need to**? A `ref struct` is a new type of struct in C#, but that's not what you have here, here you have a ref **parameter**, which has been supported since way back. The question I'm asking is thus if you actually have a problem or if you have constructed a problem? You **can use** `ref StructType` parameters in C# 6.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, if i need to make a custom converter. That method is abstract and it's used for deserializing (which is what i'm customizing here)

Comment: **Why**? Why can't you simply override the method **with** the `ref` parameter?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Because the C# compiler won't compile if it doesn't support C# 7.2+ versions! It complains with the error in the question above.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the `ref` keyword in the parameter list, the struct then has to be a ref struct as well. Again, the `ref` keyword in the parameter list **does not say that this is a ref struct**, it says it is a **ref parameter**.

Comment: But let me answer your question. No, you won't be able to use this in C# 6. You will need to go (back) to Json.net, or update the compiler.

Comment: The `ObsoleteAttribute` throws a warning and not an error. The code should work for now, just a warning about the future.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but it *is* a ref-struct, which is then *also* passed by-ref: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/ref/System.Text.Json.cs#L273

Comment: @JohnAlexiou `[Obsolete]` can represent a warning *or* an error; in the case of `ref struct`, it is configured to be an error (https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4LgMwASwQVwMYwYAqcsGA3gL5A= - look for the `, true`), which ref-struct compliant compilers then *recognize and deliberately ignore*. This is done *specifically* to prevent down-level compilers from trying to work with ref-struct types

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand that, but it won't help one bit to be able to somehow circumvent the override method with the ref parameter, that's my point. The issue is not with the ref parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot correctly implement a ref-struct based API using older versions of C# - the `[Obsolete]` is used *very intentionally* to prevent you from doing so (although in some other similar cases, a "mod-req" has been used to similar effect). `ref struct` has *very specific* demands, that could cause serious runtime problems if not satisfied (for example, an earlier compiler might attempt to *box* such a struct, which would be very very bad).

In short: update your C# version, or use an older version of the library which lacks this API which you cannot implement. As a third option, you could create your own library in a more recent version of C# that exists *only* to create an abstract implementation that overrides this API (perhaps with just `throw new NotSupportedException();`), and then inherit *that* from your down-level C# application. However, if the `Utf8JsonReader` API is now the *primary* (which I don't know, but *could* be the case), then this might cause the entire thing to be useless.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I had already ended up doing a variant of option 3, i.e moving this API to another project so I don't need to compile this code with the old compiler.